# Pandas Groupby to get average of each group

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Suppose I have a df -

```
Player       Challenge      Description
James          ABC              Desc1
Bob            ABC              Desc1
Bob            XYZ              Desc X
Bob            ABX101           Desc4
Alex           XYZ              Desc X           
Mark           ABC123           Desc 123 
Jessica        ABC123           Desc 123
Lynn           XYZ              Desc X
Bob            ABX101           Desc4
Alex           ABX101           Desc 4
Mark           ABC              Desc 1
Lynn           ABC              Desc 1
Mark           POQ              Desc 3
Mark           XYZ              Desc X
Mark           ABC              Desc 1
```

I can group these by Player and challenge using `groupby` -

`df.groupby(by=['Player', 'Challenge'])`

but how can I get something like a count of the challenges for each player (possibly in the next column) and then average the challenges per player?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
count_challenge=df.groupby('Player').Challenge.count()
print(count_challenge)

Player
Alex       2
Bob        4
James      1
Jessica    1
Lynn       2
Mark       5
Name: Challenge, dtype: int64
```

If you don't want count duplicates:

```
count_challenge=df.drop_duplicates(['Challenge','Player']).groupby('Player').Challenge.count()
print(count_challenge)
Player
Alex       2
Bob        3
James      1
Jessica    1
Lynn       2
Mark       4
Name: Challenge, dtype: int64
```

Then you can calculate the mean:

```
count_challenge.mean()
```

**if you want how many challenges of each type for each player**

```
count_differents_challenge=df.groupby('Player').Challenge.value_counts()
print(count_differents_challenge)

Player   Challenge
Alex     ABX101       1
         XYZ          1
Bob      ABX101       2
         ABC          1
         XYZ          1
James    ABC          1
Jessica  ABC123       1
Lynn     ABC          1
         XYZ          1
Mark     ABC          2
         ABC123       1
         POQ          1
         XYZ          1
Name: Challenge, dtype: int64
```

Comment: would that work if there 2 rows with same `player` and `challenge`? for eg. I need the column next to Bob to show 3 (# of unique challenges).

Comment: if you want to remove duplicates first do : `df.drop_duplicates(['player','challenge']).groupby('Player').Challenge.count()`.
Do you want not to count twice the same pair play-challenge?

Comment: that gives the mean of `[1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1]` instead of the mean of `[2, 3,1,1,2,4]`.

Comment: I said: `count_challenge=df.drop_duplicates(['Challenge','Player']).groupby('Player').Challenge.count()
` +  `count_challenge.mean()`

Comment: you just have to apply mean to the series where you want to calculate it:)

Comment: Sorry, I got confused with the earlier answer.. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df.pivot(index='foo', columns='bar')
```